# Dragging QPixmaps inside QGraphicsScene: how to avoid 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to implement a custom `QGraphicsScene`, and when we press the left key, it allows dragging an item, for which I use `QDrag` and pass the item data, then I overwrite the `dropEvent` event where I get element and `dropEvent` new parent. I think that `QGraphicsPixmapItem` on top of another item could be tricky, so maybe the best option is to set it as the `parentItem`.

However, I get the following error `'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter` and don't know exactly why

**graphicsscene.h**

```
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
```

**graphicsscene.cpp**

```
void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    auto its =  items(QRectF(event->scenePos() - QPointF(1,1), QSize(3,3)));
    auto val = std::find_if(its.constBegin(), its.constEnd(), [](auto const& it){ // <-- ERROR HERE
        return it->type() > QGraphicsItem::UserType;
    });
    if(val == its.constEnd())
        return;
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
        showContextMenu(event->scenePos());
    }
    else{
        createDrag(event->scenePos(), event->widget(), *val);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insight about this.

Comment: Are you limited to C++11?

Comment: Hi Guillaume Racicot, What do you mean? on my .pro file I have this `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11`

Comment: I mean, can you update to C++14?

Comment: Thanks that worked :) ! Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic lambdas are not supported in C++11. That means you cannot have a parameter with an `auto` type.

Simply update to C++14:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

This will require at least GCC 5.

Generic lambdas are a bit more tricky to support than simple lambdas because they require a template to be implemented as the lambda closure.

---

If you want to stay with C++11, you'll have to specify the type of your function parameter directly:

```
auto val = std::find_if(
    its.constBegin(),
    its.constEnd(),
    [](Item const& it) { // let Item be the 
                         // type of (*its.constBegin())
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Guillaume Racicot for the very clear explanation! :)